# fire multiple UILocalNotification on different date

Tags: ios, oop, uilocalnotification

Hi in my Application I want to display `UILocalNotification` for multiple events. For example like mothers day,New Year etc like that. So I already have the dates for all the events I don't want to get any events date anything from user. What I need is to show `UILocalNotification` on the particular dates in different months please tell is that possible to do and how to do that.

I have already tired for single `UILocaNotification` like this.

```
   - (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
  {

    NSCalendar *regCalender =[NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents *dateComponent = [regCalender components:NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit fromDate:[NSDate date]];

    [dateComponent setYear:2014];
    [dateComponent setMonth:7];
    [dateComponent setDay:9];
    [dateComponent setHour:16];
    [dateComponent setMinute:0];

    UIDatePicker *dd = [[UIDatePicker alloc]init];
   [dd setDate:[regCalender dateFromComponents:dateComponent]];
   UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc]init];
   [notification setAlertBody:@"Welcome"];
   [notification setFireDate:dd.date];
   [notification setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone]];
   notification.soundName=@"double_tone.mp3";

   NSCalendar *regCalender1 =[NSCalendar currentCalendar];
   NSDateComponents *dateComponent1 = [regCalender components:NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit fromDate:[NSDate date]];

    [dateComponent1 setYear:2014];
    [dateComponent1 setMonth:7];
    [dateComponent1 setDay:10];
    [dateComponent1 setHour:16];
    [dateComponent1 setMinute:0];

   UIDatePicker *dd1 = [[UIDatePicker alloc]init];
   [dd setDate:[regCalender1 dateFromComponents:dateComponent]];
   UILocalNotification *notification1 = [[UILocalNotification alloc]init];
   [notification1 setAlertBody:@"home"];
   [notification1 setFireDate:dd1.date];
   [notification1 setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone]];
   notification1.soundName=@"double_tone.mp3";


   [application setScheduledLocalNotifications:@[ notification, notification1 ]]; 


   }
```

I have used this code in my `Appdelegate` for single `UILocalNotificaiton` please tell how to do for multiple ones. i have tried something like this its not working.

```
    [application setScheduledLocalNotifications:@[ notification, notification1 ]];
```

Comment: Where you're doing a `setScheduledLocalNotifications` the array parameter needs to contain multiple notification items.

Comment: @Petesh im new for ios development please tell me how to pass the array notification to that

Comment: @Petesh can u please give me some samples

Comment: This is not an iOS specific problem. You need to create multiple local notification instances, add them all into an array (instead of just the one you currently create) and pass the array to be scheduled. You understand what an 'instance' is?

Comment: @Wain i have tried something like this its not working. [application setScheduledLocalNotifications:[NSArray arrayWithObject:notification]];
    [application setScheduledLocalNotifications:[NSArray arrayWithObject:notification1]];

Comment: @Wain please tell me where I'm doing wrg

Answer (score 0):

When you do this:

```
[application setScheduledLocalNotifications:[NSArray arrayWithObject:notification]];
[application setScheduledLocalNotifications:[NSArray arrayWithObject:notification1]];
```

you are, each time, replacing all of the notifications.

Instead, try:

```
[application setScheduledLocalNotifications:@[ notification, notification1 ]];
```

where you create one array with all of the notifications and schedule them at the same time.

The alternative would be to call `scheduleLocalNotification:` multiple times, but this is less efficient.

Comment: please check my edited question still its not working when i minize the app next second its showing the notification its not working properly

Comment: Please explain how you are testing. What dates are the notifications set to and what date are you testing (specific times matter)

Comment: I'm trying like time as common but date and months are different for example like mothers day wish women day and fathers day like that i need

Comment: You indicate that you create some notifications, schedule them and then close the app to test. Correct? If so, how are you waiting 'months' to see the notification at the specified date?

Comment: no i will change my date in my system and will test it once the notification working means it easy to test

Comment: Assume that the notification system works. Create 2 notifications 1 minute apart and one minute in the future. Test that. You don't need to change the system date (it should work, but there could be other complications)

Comment: please tell me wt kind of complication will come or is there any other way to make it in good way please tell me